# Question on continuous function: $g$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function: $g(x) = g(x+1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $g$ is bounded.

Can anyone give me a hint? Not sure how to start the proof.

Comment: Can you prove it is bounded on, say, $[0,1]$? If so, then you're close...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note that the function is periodic of period $1$, so it is sufficient (why?) to study it in the interval $[0, 1]$. If your $g$ was unbounded, it would have to be unbounded in the interval $[0, 1]$. But what do you know about continous functions on closed, bounded intervals?